# Pegar nome das abas em uma planilha fechada

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Olá, tenho uma lista mestra de documentos que se atualiza sozinha, ela não abre nenhum arquivo, somente utiliza a referencia para encontrar os dados, mas ocorre que alguns dos funcionários estão mudando o nome da aba, isso faz com que para atualizar a planilha eu tenha que ficar selecionando a planilha correta.

Gostaria que houvesse uma macro anterior que pegasse o nome da aba em especifico para não acontecer este erro.

Simplificando:

```
X = "='\\SERVIDOR\LOCAL\" & fld.Name & "\" & fld2.Name & "\FIT - Ficha de instrução de trabalho\[" & fld3.Name & "]Plan " & verificar_numero & "'!$H$3"
```

O meu problema esta neste pedaço:

> & "]**Plan** " & verificar_numero & "'!$H$3"

O "Plan" muda seu nome e não faço ideia de como conseguir seu nome sem entrar na planilha.

Obrigado.

Comment: Como o Worksheet está declarado?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode declarar o worksheet de duas maneiras que possibilitam a mudança de nome das abas.

- `Worksheets(1)` ou `Sheets(1)`, em que utiliza o número de index da planilha, por exemplo:

  ```
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  ws.Cells(1, 1) = "TESTE"
  ```

Irá escrever TESTE na célula `A1` da Primeira planilha criada, Se usar o index 2 na Segunda

- `Worksheets("Planilha1")` ou `Sheets("Planilha1")` utiliza o nome **EXATO** da planilha, portanto se for alterado ocorrerão erros, por exemplo, se o nome da Planilha de index 3 for mudada para Planilha1, este código irá declarar a planilha de nome Planilha1 e de index 3.
- `Planilha1` com Excel em português ou `Sheet1` se for em inglês.

> Para mais informações sobre possíveis problemas com renomeação de
>   planilhas, leia esta referência em inglês: [www.cpearson.com/excel/RenameProblems.aspx Copyright 2018, Charles H.
>   Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RenameProblems.aspx)

Verifique na lista de Projetos o nome da planilha:

[image: ![ProjectVBA]

Portanto você pode escrever um teste assim: `Planilha2.Cells(1, 1) = "TESTE"`

#### Exemplo:

O nome da planilha é teste e foi a terceira a ser criada, estes são os modos de escrever em `A1`.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = "TESTE"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = "TESTE"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("teste")
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = "TESTE"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("teste")
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = "TESTE"

    Planilha3.Cells(1, 1) = "TESTE"
```

## Nome das Planilhas

Porém, se ainda deseja o nome das planilhas.

```
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Debug.Print Sheets(i).Name
Next i
```

O `Debug.Print` de visualização pode ser substituído por alguma célula: `Cells(i, 1)=`

## EDIT:

### Utilizar o index da planilha para obter o nome da mesma

A alternativa é verificar o index da planilha e obter o nome da mesma com o método Woksheet.Name

```
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
    plan_nome = ws1.Name

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    plan_nome = ws2.Name

    Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("teste")
    plan_nome = ws3.Name

    Dim ws4 As Worksheet: Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("teste")
    plan_nome = ws4.Name

    plan_nome Planilha3.Name
```

Se as planilhas estão em outro livro do mesmo diretório, basta trocar `ThisWorkbook` por uma declaração de Workbook:

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb =  Workbooks("Pasta1.xlsx")
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(3)
```

O código ficaria:

```
X = "='\\SERVIDOR\LOCAL\" & fld.Name & "\" & fld2.Name & "\FIT - Ficha de instrução de trabalho\[" & fld3.Name & "]" & plan_nome & "'!$H$3"
```

### Outra alternativa

A outra alternativa é bloquear a troca do nome da planilha pelo usuário, em que há várias maneiras de realizar isto no Google.

Comment: oi daniel, obrigado pela resposta, mas não é exatamente isso, eu editei minha pergunta, veja se ajudou.

Comment: @LeandroFelipeMoreira Você pode utilizar o .Name para adquirir o nome da planilha e utilizar uma variável para compor a string `X`, no exemplo `plan_nome` é usado

Answer (score 2):

Sempre sugiro que ao fazer referência a uma planilha externa utilize o `CodeName` ao invés do `Name`, que o usuário pode alterar facilmente. Assim você terá o controle de onde está buscando os dados e se for o caso, inclusive, alterar o nome da planilha/aba.

Segue abaixo tela explicando como buscar o Nome e o Codinome da planilha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para utilizar no código em questão, sugiro usar da seguinte maneira:

1. Busque a planilha que deseja por meio do Codenome
2. Instancie um objeto com essa planilha
3. Retorne o nome atual da planilha (independente de qual seja)

Segue exemplo do código:

```
Sub Retorna_Nome_da_Planilha()

Dim PLANILHA As Worksheet

    Set PLANILHA = CodeName1

    ' Em sua fórmula irá utilizar o código abaixo.
    Debug.Print PLANILHA.Name

End Sub
```

Seguindo seu exemplo:

> & "]" & PLANILHA.Name & verificar_numero & "'!$H$3"

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Mas eu preciso fazer referência a uma planilha externa, no caso sem abrir esta, não estou conseguindo encaixar isso.

Comment: @LeandroFelipeMoreira para atualizar os dados ele vai abrir a planilha, ainda que vc não veja... mas abrirá o arquivo, atualiza os dados, e fecha novamente. No caso solicitado acima, basta adaptar a fórmula para pegar o `fullpath` da planilha com os dados. Vou tentar atualizar a resposta hoje e mando aqui.

Comment: Alias @LeandroFelipeMoreira no caso em questão já está em sua fórmula o caminho da planilha "\\SERVIDOR\LOCAL..." então creio que já funcione corretamente. não?

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sub Limpar_Coluna()

```
Range("A:A").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

End Sub

Sub Pega_Nome_Planilha_Local()

'-- PEGA O NOME DAS PLANILHAS DENTRO DA PASTA DE TRABALHO

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("A:A").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    'Debug.Print Sheets(i).Name
    ActiveCell.Value = Sheets(i).Name
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Sub BuscaNomePlan_Externa_Mod01()

'-- BUSCAR NOME DAS PLANILHAS EM OUTRA PASTA DE TRABALHO

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim NPlan As String
Dim NPastaTrab1 As String
Dim NPastaTrab2 As String
```

'-- Pasta de Trabalho a ser busca as Planilhas

```
Range("C2").Select
Range("A1").Select
NPastaTrab1 = Range("C1").Value
NPastaTrab2 = Range("C2").Value
```

Windows(NPastaTrab2).Activate

```
Range("A1").Select
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    'Debug.Print Sheets(i).Name
    NPlan = Sheets(i).Name
    Windows(NPastaTrab1).Activate

    ActiveCell.Value = NPlan
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Windows(NPastaTrab2).Activate

Next i
```

Windows(NPastaTrab1).Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'--- MODELO 02

Sub BuscaNomePlan_Externa_Mod02()

'-- BUSCAR NOME DAS PLANILHAS EM OUTRA PASTA DE TRABALHO

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim NPlan As String
Dim NPastaTrab1 As String
Dim NPastaTrab2 As String
```

'-- Pasta de Trabalho a ser busca as Planilhas

```
Range("C2").Select
Range("A1").Select
NPastaTrab1 = Range("C1").Value
NPastaTrab2 = Range("C2").Value

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

'-- Vai para a planilha 02

Windows(NPastaTrab2).Activate

Range("A10000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("A10000").Select
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    'Debug.Print Sheets(i).Name
    NPlan = Sheets(i).Name

    ActiveCell.Value = NPlan
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

Next i

Range("A10000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select


Windows(NPastaTrab1).Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub