# Como copiar e colar como imagem com VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Preciso copiar um gráfico e colá-lo como imagem na mesma planilha.

Estou tentando selecionar o *`range`* que contempla todo o gráfico e colar especial como arquivo `Bitmap` ou `Enchanced`. Segue código:

```
    Range("AM18:BE22").Select
     Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    With Sheets("Relatório").Range("CV18:DM22")
    .PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture

    End With
```

E ocorre o erro `1004, Erro de definição de aplicação ou objeto`.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Tente este código, neste caso irá copiar o gráfico de index 1. Caso existam mais gráficos, mudar o número de index de `ChartObjects`.

O [Método CopyPicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.copypicture.aspx) será utilizado, ocorre que você precisa copiar o objeto gráfico e não o range que ele está inserido.

```
Planilha1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture
Planilha2.Paste Planilha2.Range("CV18:DM22")
```

Para declarar qual planilha está sendo utilizada, mudar os valores de `Planilha1` e `Planilha2`. Caso possua dificuldades, refira a [este link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244987/75104).

Comment: Obrigado Daniel. Vou tentar aqui.

Se eu quisesse fazer para um Range, como ficaria? Para caso eu queira copiar outras infos.

Comment: Você quer copiar o Range com os valores das células? Isso vai depender de muitas variáveis e pode ser realizado de inúmeras formas.