# Método Replace VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Gostaria de saber como usar o método `Replace` com variáveis dinâmicas no VBA. Minha linha é :

```
Replace (Cells(endereco(linhaAtual).Row, 22), item.Value, "")
```

Neste caso a variável onde será buscado a String para troca é informada dinamicamente (`endereço` é uma função criada por mim e está funcionando perfeitamente em outros momentos, então creio que o problema não seja ela), enquanto que o valor a ser substituído é passado através de um `For Each`. Em ambos os casos os valores já são Strings.

O problema apontado pelo Excel é erro de sintaxe. 
Alguém sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: Tentou por cada expressão em uma variável? Ex.: `Dim _endereco = endereco(linhaAtual).Row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri. Era bem simples. Só precisava atribuir a uma outra variável primeiro. Fica assim:

```
Cells(endereco(linhaAtual).Row, 19) = Replace(Cells(endereco(linhaAtual).Row, 19), item.Value, "")
```

Comment: FWIW: Com `Cells` você estará utilizando o `AtiveSheet` por padrão, caso existam múltiplas planilhas na pasta de trabalho, o recomendado é definir uma variável da planilha desejada para evitar erros. [Veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244987/75104) para ver como fazer isso.